# Please extend the window for editing comments

Tags: feature-request, comments, comment-edits

I find myself editing my comments a lot, mostly fixing minor errors. Seeing a large quantity of  comments that have the same errors,  other users suffer from the same issue.

Soometimes there's an extra space in the sentence, or an extra "o" in a word . Occasionally will I skip a small word or up swapping two words around. Or maybe I find that my comments has stupid pluralization error.

Whatever the error is, it's beyond minor. By the time the writer returns from where-ever and realizes that they have to make such a minor fix, though, it already says "4 mins ago" and time is running out! To hover on the comment, click edit, make the change, and hit Save edits probably takes no longer than 4-6 seconds. But lo, in that mere blink of an eye, it's already 5 mins ago!

**I propose that we extend the window for editing comments by 8 seconds**. It's too short for editors to make substantial changes to the comment. Because most people don't bother with spans of time between 5 and 10 seconds, no one  will notice that the change was made *ever so slightly later* than 5 minutes.

And yet, for those people who rightfully notice *just in time* that they need to make a minor fix, it's a welcome window to accomplish their task and avoid everlasting SHAME!

Comment: Sort of an, um...Grace period? :P

Comment: Can you not just let the comment go?

Comment: I was going to edit for grammer... but having re-read the post, I'm starting to the small errors were part of the argument...

Comment: @staticbeast: The correct spelling is "grammar", not "grammer". You're also missing the word "see" between "to" and "the". A comma is more appropriate than an ellipsis at the beginning of your sentence, and a period is the proper punctuation for the end of it.

Comment: @Wesley Murch Ah... sure wish I could edit that comment.  Grammar is good to know, that's why I should use a spell checker.  The actual word I had was "think", not "see", but it really does need a word there. The ellipsis was used correctly to indicate an intentional pause, trailing off into silence, rather than a direct end. I'll concede that the first ellipsis should be a comma :)

Comment: Or you could just tell users they have 4:52 to make an edit; no coding change needed!

Comment: Related: http://meta.english.stackexchange.com/q/4833

Answer (score 2):

I've proposed a solution here: [Add "You have less than x seconds left for editing" warning while editing post comments](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/147298/add-you-have-less-than-x-seconds-left-for-editing-warning-while-editing-post-c)

This would allow users enough time to finish their edit, without uncertainty about how much time is left for editing.